# Java - how to extract multiple things from a string and store in an object

Tags: java, string, split

```
  public class Main{


  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    String a = "PORT:AXN,0,10;BGT,20,30;CXZ,10,30|BENCH:AXN,50,10;BGT,30,30;DFG,30,20;XYZ,0,10";
   Port port = new Port();
   Port bench = new Port();

   }
   }


  public class Port{
  List<String> name = new ArrayList<String>();
  List<Integer> qty = new ArrayList<Integer>();
  List<Integer> price = new ArrayList<Integer>();
  }
```

I want to go through the string and store the information in these objects so 
port object gets:
AXN,BGT,CXZ in the name list
0,20,10 in the qty list
10,30,30 in the price list

And similarly for the bench object using the bench data in the string.

In the string, there can be any number of tuples in the string for each. eg. port can have 5 sets, bench can have 8. And the codes for each (the name) have to be 3 alpha characters long but can be anything.

How can I go about doing this? The only thing I can think of is using the split method somehow but am having a hard time working out exactly how to use it? Any help would be great! thanks

Comment: By using `String.split()`, as the format is said to be consistent, you can first split by `|` character (to get the list of `Port`) then by `:` (to have the port name and the port object list), then by `;` (to separate the port object) and finally by `,`. This is doable but a pretty hard to read. Can you consider a class named `PortObject` and having a constructor such as `PortObject axn = new PortObject("AXN,0,10")`? Then you'll have a `List<PortObject>` in your `Port` class

Comment: thats a good idea actually! ill give it a go! thanks :)

Comment: Actually, if you like the `PortObject` class idea, you can go for it with also the `Port` constructor which looks like `Port port = new Port("PORT:AXN,0,10;BGT,20,30;CXZ,10,30");` where, after splitting by `:` and `;`, you can call the PortObject constructor I mentioned. You'll unfortunately go through the same split but I think you'll gain much more readibility

Comment: did things work for you?

Answer (score 0):

You can use split with some loops like this :

```
String a ="PORT:AXN,0,10;BGT,20,30;CXZ,10,30|BENCH:AXN,50,10;BGT,30,30;DFG,30,20;XYZ,0,10";
Port port = new Port();

String[] tuples = a.split("\\|");
//Split with | to get the tuples 
//PORT:AXN,0,10;BGT,20,30;CXZ,10,30 
//BENCH:AXN,50,10;BGT,30,30;DFG,30,20;XYZ,0,10

for(String tuple : tuples){

    String[] objects = tuple.split(";");//split each tuple with ; to get the information
    //PORT:AXN,0,10 
    //BGT,20,30 
    //CXZ,10,30

    for(String obj : objects){

        //split with , to get the three properties(name, qty, price)
        String[] spl = obj.replaceAll("(.*?):(.*?)", "$2").split(",");

        port.name.add(spl[0]);//name value
        port.qty.add(Integer.parseInt(spl[1]));//qty value
        port.price.add(Integer.parseInt(spl[2]));//price value
    }            
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## Classes

As I suggested, I think modifying a bit your `Port` class and creating a `PortObject` class could improve readibility. Basically:

- A port has a name and a list of port objects
- A port object has a name, a quantity and a price:

For each class, I'll create two constructor:

1. constructor which takes all attributes and assign
2. constructor which build object from a raw `String` input

<sub>Classes are `private static` and don't have getter because I put everything in the `Main.java` but this is not a good practice!</sub>

**Port class**

```
private static class Port {

    final String name;
    final List<PortObject> portObjects;

    // format is PORT:AXN,0,10;BGT,20,30;CXZ,10,30
    public Port(String input) {
        String[] split = input.split(":");
        name = split[0];

        this.portObjects = Pattern.compile(";").splitAsStream(split[1])
                .map(PortObject::new)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    public Port(String name, List<PortObject> portObjects) {
        this.name = name;
        this.portObjects = portObjects;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Port:" + name + " " + portObjects.toString();
    }
}
```

**Port object class**

```
private static class PortObject {

    final String name;
    final int qty;
    final int price;

    // format is AXN,0,10
    public PortObject(String input) {
        String[] split = input.split(",");
        name = split[0];
        qty = Integer.parseInt(split[1]);
        price = Integer.parseInt(split[2]);
    }

    public PortObject(String name, int qty, int price) {
        this.name = name;
        this.qty = qty;
        this.price = price;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return name + ":" + qty + ":" + price;
    }
}
```

## Not a so good idea: Regex

When it's about matching a pattern, one may think about Regex. Regex will require the second constructor (the one which does not take a raw `String` input as argument). I'm not a Regex expert so I'll do a simple way:

1. `[^\\|]+` is the equivalent of `String.split("\\|")`
2. `(\\w+):(.*)` will match the port name and the list of port objects. This list will be processed by the next regex:
3. `(\\w{3}),(\\d+),(\\d+);?` will match the three-characters port object name, ask for a digit-only quantity and a digit-only price followed by an optional semi-colon (optional because the last port object does not have semi-colon)

Put in code, it looks like as follow:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    // the input
    String a = "PORT:AXN,0,10;BGT,20,30;CXZ,10,30|BENCH:AXN,50,10;BGT,30,30;DFG,30,20;XYZ,0,10";

    // Option 1: Regex
    List<Port> portList1 = new ArrayList<>();
    
    // initialise regex
    String splitRegex = "[^\\|]+";                          // Regex 1.
    String portRegex = "(\\w+):(.*)";                       // Regex 2.
    String portObjectRegex = "(\\w{3}),(\\d+),(\\d+);?";    // Regex 3.
    Pattern patternSplit = Pattern.compile(splitRegex);
    Pattern patternPort = Pattern.compile(portRegex);
    Pattern patternPortObject = Pattern.compile(portObjectRegex);
    Matcher matcherSplit = patternSplit.matcher(a);
    Matcher matcherPort;
    Matcher matcherPortObject;
    // look for each port
    while (matcherSplit.find()) {
        String portSplit = matcherSplit.group();
        matcherPort = patternPort.matcher(portSplit);
        while (matcherPort.find()) {
            // keep the port name 
            String name = matcherPort.group(1);

            List<PortObject> portObjectList = new ArrayList<>();
            matcherPortObject = patternPortObject.matcher(matcherPort.group(2));
            // look for each port object
            while (matcherPortObject.find()) {
                String poName = matcherPortObject.group(1);
                int poQty = Integer.parseInt(matcherPortObject.group(2));
                int poPrice = Integer.parseInt(matcherPortObject.group(3));
                portObjectList.add(new PortObject(poName, poQty, poPrice));
            }
            portList1.add(new Port(name, portObjectList));
        }
    }

    // Print
    System.out.println("PortList1:\n" + portList1 + "\n");
}
```

The output is

> PortList1:
>
> [Port:PORT [AXN:0:10, BGT:20:30, CXZ:10:30], Port:BENCH [AXN:50:10, BGT:30:30, DFG:30:20, XYZ:0:10]]

## Most likely a better idea: Split + Stream

Honestly speaking, I didn't know that split can directly be turned into a Stream. It basically leverages the [`Pattern.compile(yourRegex).splitAsStream(yourInput)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#splitAsStream-java.lang.CharSequence-). As I said, this is a long split way but as the split are dispatched in `Port` constructor and `PortObject` constructor, it makes it easier to read:

Put in code, it is much shorter:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    // the input
    String a = "PORT:AXN,0,10;BGT,20,30;CXZ,10,30|BENCH:AXN,50,10;BGT,30,30;DFG,30,20;XYZ,0,10";

    // Option 2: Split with Stream:
    List<Port> portList2 = Pattern.compile("\\|").splitAsStream(a)
            .map(Port::new)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

    // Print
    System.out.println("PortList2:\n" + portList2 + "\n");
}
```

Obviously, the output is the same:

> PortList2:
>
> [Port:PORT [AXN:0:10, BGT:20:30, CXZ:10:30], Port:BENCH [AXN:50:10, BGT:30:30, DFG:30:20, XYZ:0:10]]